# como dejar un repositorio de git

Tags: git

he confundido con el directorio que debería de ser el repositorio de git. y quiero que vuelva a ser un directorio normal. Existe manera de hacerlo.

lo que he hecho es git init a un directorio.

Comment: Al hacer `git init` simplemente se crea una carpeta dentro de esa, llamada `.git`. En unix no la ves porque los nombres de carpeta o archivo que comienzan por punto no se muestran con `ls` a menos que pongas `ls -a`. Basta que borres esa carpeta `.git` con todo su contenido

Comment: a mi me parece una muy buena respuesta que deberías considerar colocar @abulafia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asciendo a respuesta mi comentario:

Al hacer `git init` simplemente se crea una carpeta dentro de esa, llamada `.git` donde git guarda la copia local del repositorio y toda la meta-información que necesita para funcionar.

En unix no la ves porque los nombres de carpeta o archivo que comienzan por punto no se muestran con `ls` a menos que pongas `ls -a`. En Windows sí es perfectamente visible.

Basta que borres esa carpeta `.git` con todo su contenido (en Linux puedes hacerlo con un `rm -rf .git`)

Comment: windows para borrar `rmdir .git /S /Q` `/Q` = modo silencioso , `/S` = modo recursivo, lo que falta por explicar en esta respuesta que siginifica `rm -rf` = `rm` es remove `-r` = recursivo `-f `= forzar

Comment: @JackNavaRow Gracias por aportarlo. En windows suelo usar para esto el explorador de archivos :-)